# Redux architecture: multiple items editable on same page with new item form

Tags: react-redux, redux-form

I have list of items on single screen. The list is fetched from redux store and rendered as set of form components. At the bottom of list I have "Add new" button.

In my initial implementation I have used container component with `setState({newItem: {...})`. **This has side effect of view flickering when newItem is cleared and new item is added to redux items.**

```
    {items.map((item, index) =>
      <ItemForm
        key={index}
        formKey={index.toString()}
        initialValues={item}
        submitItem={this.handleUpdateItem.bind(this)}
        removeItem={() => this.handleRemoveItem(item.id)}
      />
    )}

    {newItem &&
      <ItemForm
        key="new"
        formKey="new"
        initialValues={newItem}
        submitItem={this.handleCreateItem.bind(this)}
        removeItem={() => this.handleRemoveNewItem()}
      />
    }
```

I think better way to implement this would be not to use newItem and instead handle the new item inside redux. But in that case I have to change the actions/reducers API, in particular the CREATE_ITEM would no longer append item but rather updates the last item in store.

Is there some way I can reduce the flickering or do you have some suggestions how to do it with redux? In particular - what set of actions / reducers should I use to model better solution? Should I rather make API calls in container and simplify the redux actions?

The complexity of the actions/reducers API for me comes from mixing persisted (requires id to make request) and not persisted objects (requires index to find) in redux.

Here is my redux module:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import * as _ from 'lodash';

export const FETCH_ITEMS = 'items/FETCH_ITEMS';
export const CREATE_ITEM = 'items/CREATE_ITEM';
export const REMOVE_ITEM = 'items/REMOVE_ITEM';
export const UPDATE_ITEM = 'items/UPDATE_ITEM';

const initialState = {
  items: []
};

export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  let index;

  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_ITEMS:
      return {
        ...state,
        items: action.items
      };
    case CREATE_ITEM: // would become "last item UPDATE_ITEM"
      return {
        ...state,
        items: [
          ...state.items,
          action.item
        ]
      };
    case REMOVE_ITEM:
      index = _.findIndex(state.items, {id: action.id});
      return {
        ...state,
        items: [
          ...state.items.slice(0, index),
          action.item,
          ...state.items.slice(index + 1)
        ]
      };
    case UPDATE_ITEM:
      index = _.findIndex(state.items, {id: action.item.id});
      return {
        ...state,
        items: [
          ...state.items.slice(0, index),
          action.item,
          ...state.items.slice(index + 1)
        ]
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export function fetchItems() {
  return function (dispatch) {
    return axios.get('/api/items')
      .then(res => {
        const items = res.data;
        dispatch({type: FETCH_ITEMS, items});
      })
  }
}

export function createItem(item) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    return axios.post('/api/items', item)
      .then(res => {
        const item = res.data.item;
        dispatch({type: CREATE_ITEM, item});
      })
  }
}

export function removeItem(id) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    return axios.delete(`/api/items/${id}`)
      .then(() => {
        dispatch({type: REMOVE_ITEM, id});
      });
  }
}

export function updateItem(item) {
  const {id, ...rest} = item;

  return function (dispatch) {
    return axios.put(`/api/items/${id}`, rest)
      .then(res => {
        const item = deserializeItem(res.data.item);
        dispatch({type: UPDATE_ITEM, item});
      })
  }
}
```